# repository binding problem with spring r2dbc

Tags: spring, repository, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc

I try to use Spring R2DBC with postgres driver. I have the following repository:

```
package fr.misc.database.repos.computed;

import fr.misc.database.entities.computed.OrdreDeTravailPivotComputedEntity;
import org.springframework.data.repository.reactive.ReactiveCrudRepository;

public interface OrderRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository<OrderEntity, String> {

}
```

And I tried several annotations like that:

```
package fr.misc;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.data.r2dbc.repository.config.EnableR2dbcRepositories;

@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"fr.misc.database.repos.common"})
@EntityScan("fr.misc")
@ComponentScan("fr.misc")
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@EnableR2dbcRepositories("fr.misc.database.repos.computed")
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

With my connection factory like this:

```
package fr.misc;

import io.r2dbc.spi.ConnectionFactories;
import io.r2dbc.spi.ConnectionFactory;
import io.r2dbc.spi.ConnectionFactoryOptions;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.r2dbc.config.AbstractR2dbcConfiguration;

@Configuration
public class DatabaseConfiguration extends AbstractR2dbcConfiguration {

    @Value("${spring.data.postgres.host")
    private String host;
    @Value("${spring.data.postgres.port}")
    private int port;
    @Value("${spring.data.postgres.database}")
    private String database;
    @Value("${spring.data.postgres.username}")
    private String username;
    @Value("${spring.data.postgres.password}")
    private String password;

    @Override
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
//      return new PostgresqlConnectionFactory(PostgresqlConnectionConfiguration.builder().host(host)
//              .port(port).database(database).username(username).password(password).build());
        return ConnectionFactories.get(ConnectionFactoryOptions.builder()
                .option(DRIVER, POSTGRESQL_DRIVER)
                .option(DATABASE, database)
                .option(HOST, host)
                .option(PORT, port)
                .option(PASSWORD, password)
                .option(USER, username)
                .build());
    }
}
```

and the application.yml:

```
  data:
    postgres:
      host: locahost
      port: 5432
      database: postgres
      username: postgres
      password: postgres
```

But I always got the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'orderConverter' defined in file [../converters/OrderConverter.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'fr.misc.database.repos.computed.OrderRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:798)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1358)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:879)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:126)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    ... 63 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'ffr.misc.database.repos.computed.OrderRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1695)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1253)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1207)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:885)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:789)
    ... 81 more
```

And bellow my OrderConverter constructor:

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class OrderConverter {

    private final OrderComputedRepository   orderComputedRepository;

    @Autowired
    public OrderConverter(OrderComputedRepository orderComputedRepository) {
        this.orderComputedRepository = orderComputedRepository;
    }
```

Do you have an idea why my repository bean isn't bound ?

Thank all and best regards

Adrian

Comment: You mixed blocking and none-blocking in the same application, try to use `SpringApplicationBuilder` in the `main` method to specify your application type.

Comment: I have [an example](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-reactive-sample/tree/master/java8) for using blocking JPA in a reactive application, not added more reactive facilities.

Answer (score 0):

The error says:

> No qualifying bean of type 'ffr.misc.database.repos.computed.OrderRepository'

Looks like there is an additional 'f' at the beginning of your package.
So I don't know if the code you shared is the exact one, but at least it does not match your annotation

> @EnableR2dbcRepositories("fr.misc.database.repos.computed")